# PostgreSQL: Return entries based on conditions and grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Imagine the following table:

```
result_id student subject grade
1         Anne    A      63
2         Anne    B      63
3         Bob     A      89
4         Bob     B      51
5         Carla   A      70
6         Carla   B      70
7         Carla   C      68
8         Dylan   B      75
9         Dylan   C      54
```

I would like to return the entries where a student got the exact same grade for subject A and B. So the ideal output would be:

```
result_id student subject grade
1         Anne    A      63
2         Anne    B      63
5         Carla   A      70
6         Carla   B      70
```

Can this even be achieved with queries? Struggling to find information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit complicated but I hope easy to read.

```sql
select * from the_table
where student in
(
 with t as 
 (
  select student, count(*) cnt, min(grade) mig, max(grade) mag 
  from the_table 
  where subject in ('A', 'B') group by student
 )
 select student from t where mig = mag and cnt = 2
) 
and subject in ('A', 'B') 
order by student, subject;
```

| result_id | student | subject | grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anne | A | 63 |
| 2 | Anne | B | 63 |
| 5 | Carla | A | 70 |
| 6 | Carla | B | 70 |